# Update all slugs in all languages of all pages in TYPO3 10

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

Is there a possibility to update all slugs of all pages in all languages?

In an installation of one of my clients are hundreds of pages in multiple languages with wrong slugs (e.g.: prefix translate+german page name instead of translated page name etc.).

I remember an upgrade wizard in TYPO3 v9 but in version i cannot find this wizard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TYPO3 9.5 LTS - Automatic (re)generation of URL Segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007858/typo3-9-5-lts-automatic-regeneration-of-url-segments)

Comment: Do you want to fix existing slugs or regenerate them again from scratch (by using the title)?

Answer (score 2):

This upgrade wizards appears if you just empty all slug fields of the table `pages` which is the fastest way to renew all slugs.

Answer (score 0):

For special cases, maybe you would like to build your own [Command](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/CommandControllers/Index.html).

Some nice thoughts (and helper methods) have been collected under [TYPO3/Extbase How to create unique slug within create action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63304723/typo3-extbase-how-to-create-unique-slug-within-create-action)